# How to undo youtube changes for an uploaded video

Tags: youtube, pytube

When i upload a movie to youtube and then download it from the given link, it is the same movie but the files bites are altered...
is there a way to undo youtube encoding so the file i upload and the file i downloaded will be 100% the same??

i am downloading using python pytube

Thanks

```
from pytube import YouTube
import defines
# not necessary, just for demo purposes.
from pprint import pprint

yt = YouTube(defines.url)

# Once set, you can see all the codec and quality options YouTube has made
# available for the perticular video by printing videos.

pprint(yt.get_videos())

# [<Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) - 144p>,
#  <Video: MPEG-4 Visual (.3gp) - 240p>,
#  <Video: Sorenson H.263 (.flv) - 240p>,
#  <Video: H.264 (.flv) - 360p>,
#  <Video: H.264 (.flv) - 480p>,
#  <Video: H.264 (.mp4) - 360p>,
#  <Video: H.264 (.mp4) - 720p>,
#  <Video: VP8 (.webm) - 360p>,
#  <Video: VP8 (.webm) - 480p>]

# The filename is automatically generated based on the video title.  You
# can override this by manually setting the filename.

# view the auto generated filename:
print(yt.filename)
# Pulp Fiction - Dancing Scene [HD]

# set the filename:
# yt.set_filename('Dancing Scene from Pulp Fiction')

# You can also filter the criteria by filetype.
pprint(yt.filter('flv'))


print(yt.filter('mp4')[-1])
# <Video: H.264 (.mp4) - 720p>

# You can also get all videos for a given resolution
pprint(yt.filter(resolution='480p'))

# [<Video: H.264 (.flv) - 480p>,
# <Video: VP8 (.webm) - 480p>]



video = yt.get('3gp', '240p')

# NOTE: get() can only be used if and only if one object matches your         criteria.
# for example:

pprint(yt.videos)  

video = yt.get('webm')
video.download('here1.webm')
```

Answer (score 0):

Youtube is encoding videos to save bandwith and to minimize unnessecary web traffic. The files get encoded on the youtube servers and the original most likely get deleted in the process.

Also why would you even do that ? You can transfer/share files (if thats what youre after) over various other services or protocols like ftp or dropbox and the like.

Comment: i need it for Authentication reasons so i will know to recognize  the video as the origin one..

Comment: after the files have been encoded theres no way I know of that you can do that would allow this.